# Countdown timer from JSON

Tags: java, android

I get data from an api, which has time in seconds

```
{
    "now": [{
            "time": {
                "starts_in": 0,
                "ends_in": 2272,
                "starts_at": 0,
                "ends_at": "2018-01-27T08:00:00.205Z"
           },
```

I want to make the `ends_in` time to countdown and append it in a textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all parse your `ends_in` parameter from your json and and put in some `int endsIn` variable and then if you have `TextView timerTextView`:

```
new CountDownTimer(endsIn * 1000, 1000) { 
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
           timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000);
 } 
public void onFinish() {
} 
}.start();
```